# Touch manipulations with AddManipulator

Tags: c#, wpf

When using AddManipulator, are touches routed to the new Manipulation? When I do the following, it all works but touches are left after the TouchLeave event. So for example if I do a single finger rotate, leave the touched element and touch it again, it becomes a two finger zoom.

```
private void HV3DTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas canvas = sender as Canvas
    Manipulation.AddManipulator(canvas, e.TouchDevice.AsManipulator());
    e.Handled = true;
    CaptureTouch(e.TouchDevice);
}

private void HV3DTouchLeave(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas canvas = sender as Canvas
    Manipulation.RemoveManipulator(canvas, e.TouchDevice.AsManipulator());
    e.Handled = true;
    ReleaseTouchCapture(e.TouchDevice);
}
```

Comment: Is `this` (i.e. the object you're calling `CaptureTouch` on) the same as `canvas`? If not, you're doing strange things. As soon as the Canvas gets a `TouchDown`, you call `this.CaptueTouch` which will immediately steal the touch from the Canvas and generate a `TouchLeave`, which will in turn result in a `this.ReleaseTouch`. Moreover, calling `CaptureTouch` generates a `GotTouchCapture` event, which also calls `AddManipulator` if unhandled. And this is the "left-over" manipulator you observe.

Comment: Please explain why you can't live with the default way of generating manipulation events, and what exactly you are trying to achieve. Also, i strongly suggest to read [Touch and Manipulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010(v=vs.110).aspx#touch_and_manipulation), especially section "The Relationship Between Touch and Manipulation Events".

Comment: @Clemens Thanks, I'm working on a Pixelsense device and this item control is on a ScatterviewItem which confuses the issue slightly. I'm certainly taking your advice into account. I'm actually adding the manipulator because for some reason it won't bubble and the canvas is just psuedo code. It's seems quite difficult to debug current manipulations.

Comment: Clemens is quite correct here. The following also assisted http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pixelsense/archive/2011/09/29/a-word-on-wpf4-manipulations.aspx